# ASP.NET MVC 5 Async Context Management

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await, c#-5.0

I have a fairly standard MVC 5 application consisting of a repository layer, service layer and a controller layer. To keep each layer decoupled and testable I am using Ninject for dependency injection.

To brush up on new skill I have decided to make use of the new new Task controller actions with async / await on IO bound operations for service and controller methods.

Normally I just make use of the InRequestScope binding like so

```
kernel.Bind<IDbContext>().To<BlogContext>().InRequestScope();
```

In general this is working fine now, however if I chose to debug my application, or join multiple tracked entity framework objects together and save, I'm finding the context has been disposed or I'm getting tracking issues. I see why this is happening, it's perfectly logical because the operation is no longer taking place on the IIS thread, so how would Ninject know that it should be using the same context.

To work around this I can pass my context into each repository call from my service layer or even down from the controller layer if need be. However I feel this looks messy and I'd rather Ninject manage the context of this object if possible.

What are the best strategies for handling this in an elegant / minimalistic manner whilst keeping my code similar to the examples given below?

Here is an example of one of my controller methods

```
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id)
    {
        var editViewModel = await BuildDefaultCreateEditViewModel();

        var post = await postService.GetNonDeletedPost(id);
        ...
        ...
        return View(MVC.Admin.Post.Views.CreateEdit, editViewModel);
    }
```

Service method

```
    public async Task<PostDTO> GetNonDeletedPost(int postId)
    {
        return (await PostRepostiory.GetPost(postId)).ConvertToDTO();
    }
```

Repository method

```
    public Task<Post> GetPost(int postId)
    {
        return QueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(
                DbSet.Where(post => post.PostId == postId)
                .Include(post => post.PostVersions)
                .Include(post => post.Categories)
                .Include(post => post.Files));
    }
```

Comment: Do you use a DbContextFactory? I tend to use the `TransientScope` instead of Request, and I never get any issues

Comment: I was effectively hoping that I could use Ninject in a similar manner to a DbContextFactory similar to using InRequestScope. 

If I were to go down the route of using a DBContextFacotry the problem of how I know which request the asynchronous thread belongs to is still apparent, how do I negate this?

As for using transient scope that will create a new context per repository which is fine for services that use one but when I'm using several (Facade pattern) stitching objects together and saving will not work as objects from different repositories will be under different tracked contexts.

Comment: Thats how I use ninject, with the DbContextFactory, it allows me to inject the context into the repository all in the TransientScope. :)

Comment: Sorry your this 'postService' field every per request dependent use Niject or actuality by default MVC?

Comment: If you not intensive compile to IOC , try very easy build context with [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) ,and simple build use this [action](http://coderdiaries.com/2014/02/05/unitofwork-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc-with-autofac/)

Comment: it looks like the object gets disposed before you manage to read out of it. When you execute your repository method, assign it into local variable and return it.

Answer (score 1):

In your post and in the related comments there are some great examples of how to do this.

However, for some other readers that might stumble here, I want to throw out an honest question: **Do you even really need asynchronous controllers?**

Asynchronous controller actions free up the number of threads needed to handle requests; however, if you're not running out of threads and not likely to, then you're creating complexity while trying to solve a problem you neither have nor expect to have.  Or: **"Is Async truly free and always better?"**

Effectively, I'm trying to showcase that one very viable solution (and perhaps not the one you are looking for), would be to simply not use asynchronous controllers - if indeed not needed (which would depend on your specific circumstances.)

That good old wacky solution of solving the problem by removing the problem.  And particularly, I propose it because removing complexity appears to be one of the goals.

**How to Choose Which to use?**  there is a longer list, but two of the best questions are:

- **Are your items short running?**
- **And if not, are your items CPU bound?**

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

From the above link **"Using asynchronous action methods on CPU-bound operations provides no benefits and results in more overhead."**